# Why LoadFile(path) is always getting pointing to 4.0 framework even though i am giving 2.0 framework path?

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, .net-framework-version

i written some basic code snippet which is below :
and the project is targeted to .net framework 4.0

For the loadForm() i gave the input path of system.web.dll of all .net framework version<4.

always i am resulted the output of 4.0 .net framework

code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(
        @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Web.dll");
    Console.WriteLine(asm.FullName);
}
```

Orginal Output:

its giving the full path of system.web.dll("System.Web.dll, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35")

expected Output:

I need the exact choosen path of system.web.dll(of version 2.0.0.0);

Please Tell me What changes can be made to achieve this phenomenon.

Answer (score 1):

See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2004/11/03/252033.aspx); basically:

- the GAC is preferred
- System.Web is present in the GAC
- therefore, you get the version from the GAC
- which is the 4.x version

If you look at the `.CodeBase`, you'll see the GAC mentioned.

Depending on what you want to do, `ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom` may work.

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(
    @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Web.dll");
Console.WriteLine(asm.FullName);
```

Shows:

```
System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
```